# Using GoogleDistanceMatrix Service to Restrict Area of search

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using GoogleDistanceMatrix to calculate the driving distance between two points with the inputs coming from two text boxes.
But being in a place i want to restrict the search results ( the assist in the text boxes) to show only places from my country or even my state itself.
The Code is as :

```
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [source],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;

            } else {
                alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
            }
        });
```

Can Someone tell me how do i restrict the search result.I am also looking at this as a heavy use thing, so what else is a possible good option for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first use the [geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests) to find the place and pass its place ID and then feed it to the direction API.

In the geocoding API, you can use `bounds` or `region` to define your search area.